# Changing a specific Instance without ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, let's say that I have multiple links on a page and I want links to change background color when you roll over them. I would use this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').mouseover(function() {
        $('a').css('background-color', 'black');
    });
}); 
$(function() {
    $('a').mouseleave(function() {
        $('a').css('background-color', 'white');
    });
});
```

the problem with this code is that when you roll over one a, all of the links change color. I could give each a a specific ID and make a specific function for each, but is there a more efficient way to do this?
Edit: Additionally, what could I do to set the original background color back to the way it was. If I turn the background back to white, It might not have been white in the first place. How could I fix this?

Comment: For this specific task I'd use the `a:hover { background-color: black; }` with css. But maybe you're not just asking about changing style when hovering links.

Comment: +1 to @LarsNyström. Also, you don't need/want to wrap each bit of code in `$(function() {...});`. Just wrap it all in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know, you're all going about it the long and hard way.

```
// this is like document.onload = function, 
//  this only needs to be called once, you can put 
//  all your jQuery in this one function
$(function() {
    // the following is a call to all `a` links to add jQuery's own .hover function
    // see -> http://api.jquery.com/hover/
    $("a").hover(function(eIn) { // this first function is the action taken when
                                 // user hovers over the link
        $(this).css({ 'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff' });
    }, function(eOut) { // this second function is what happens 
                        // when user hover away from the link
        $(this).css({ 'background-color': '', 'color': '' });
    });
});
```

[​See WORKING Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/8beT8/)

***ALSO, YOU DONT NEED JQUERY FOR THIS, USE CSS***

In CSS:

```
a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}​
```

[See it in CSS ONLY HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/jgcHH/)

Answer (score 4):

In your version you use `$('a')` to call the `.css()` function on. The Problem is that `$('a')` selects ALL the a nodes on the page and not only the one that you moved your mouse over. Within the mouseover callback function the `this` keyword references the node that was the originator of the event. So when you do `$(this)` within that function you'll create a jQuery object (called a wrapped set) of that node. Now you can call all jquery functions on it, uncluding the `.css()` function. So here you go:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
    });
}); 
$(function() {
    $('a').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });
});
```

Comment: Please explain why this works. I know why it does, as do many others, but it may not be apparent to the OP.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Just what I was looking for. :D

Comment: Jam, I think I understand. I think the term "this" is targeting the specific instance of that a. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I explained it in my answer. Thanks to JamWaffles for pointing out that obvious shortcoming.

Comment: I have another small question. Let's say that the background color wasn't originally white. Is there a way that I could set the background to the original way it was, no matter what the previous background color was?

Comment: You would have to save the color during page initialization and refer to that saved color from  then on. It's best to post a new question so  people can provide a new code snippet of how to do this. It is hard to do so in the comments